# How did this edit get approved?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, specific-edit, specific-audit

How did [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70853500/2) get approved? I noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70853500/python-pandas-colab-how-to-convert-numpy-ndarray-to-a-json) and made an edit, but couldn't save it then because it showed this error:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot
> be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

Sometime later, I go to the tab containing the post (I had two tabs open - one in which I was editing the post and the other for viewing it) and see that it's been edited by someone already, but my eyes couldn't spot any changes at the first quick glance, so I opened the revision (to see the differences).

How can an edit with the edit summary "Fixed Grammer" be approved? I don't know how it's for and what options the approver has, but these were the changes made:

1. Added a comma to help break the sentence.
2. This is the sentence in which the main changes were made: "Maybe there is <s>a</s>**the** best way to accomplish this task without <s>iterate trough</s>**iterating through** this array and <s>create</s>**creating** the JSON?".

I agree that the comma and the changes in tense are constructive, but the <s>a</s>"the" only makes it more confusing.

Comment: Because the OP approved it, they can unilaterally approve/reject any suggested edits on their posts.

Comment: @Nick, oh, is there any way to find out who approved the edit, or at least if it was approved by the OP or the *community*?

Comment: If you click the "edit approved 1 hour ago" in the revision history, it takes you to the suggested edit review.

Comment: Link to the [suggested edit review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30906862) in question.

Comment: On an off-note, that's far from the worst edit that could be approved with that summary :) A slightly ranty note: I can't fathom how editors keep messing up the word "grammar" en masse... (really, how hard can it be to spell it correctly?)

Comment: No, really, just take a look at [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1548389) - that is a complete mystery to me...

Comment: @OlegValter Maybe that town is just popular

Comment: Woah, that's a lot... 50000 rows- I don't know either. Maybe in many cases, it's because "A" and "E" aren't too far away from each other.

Comment: @KevinB seems like the editor population there is hella densely packed :) For the benefit of other readers: 39°09′10″N 85°43′30″W

Comment: @OlegValter It's often a good indicator of issues in the suggestion, I've been complaining about it recently in DMs with people.

Comment: [Slightly revised](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1548389) (prettified) version of the query - not for the faint-hearted [you have been warned].

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder also don't forget that 50K is just a hard limit on how many rows a given query can return at a time... And that's only counting *approved* suggested edits.

Comment: @OlegValter Here you go Oleg: [Total approved edits with "grammer" over time by month](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1548415/#graph). Apparently March of 2018 was an exceptionally bad month for grammar, it had 1,205 misspellings (the most so far) lol

Comment: I can relate to people writing it as "grammer" for two reasons: 1) that's what it sounds like when spoken. 2) the spellchecker doesn't mark it as wrong, at least not for me. Heck even "fix speling" passes the spellcheck for me, probably because it is a Dutch word. We can't have nice things.

Comment: @Gimby nah, reason #1 would lead to editors spelling "grammar" as "gremmer" :) [Oh, wait](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1548389/approved-suggested-edits-with-the-comment-containing-text?Text=gremmer)...

Comment: @OlegValter What grinds my gears the most is that the first hit only has (excessive) formatting changes, no gremmer fixs.

Comment: @Gimby for the sake of our collective sanity I urge everyone to not actually open those edits :) Sigh, this discussion is somewhat bittersweet.

Comment: True... "anotatoin an fixed gremmer" and "gremmer mastakes" made me laugh :D

Answer (score 0):

It was likely approved because it corrects the English to be grammatically correct.

The title or explanation of the edit isn't content that goes into the posting, so if its title or description of the edit itself has grammar errors, it doesn't impact the improvement of the quality of the post.

As you agree with most of the changes, I'll only comment on the one you disagree with.

"Best" implies that there is no better way, which means that there is a **single** best way, not one of many best ways.  For single items that stand alone, "the" is preferred definitive article.  For single items that are a member of a group, "a" is the preferred definitive article.

- The best carpenter is (the) John Stephens of Cincinnati.
- The best carpenters include (a) John Stephens of Cincinnati.

Of course, in my example, it's completely appropriate (as it often is) to not use a definitive article at all.

Comment: It still should have been "Maybe the best way" or "Maybe there is a better way" as someone has since changed it to.

Comment: @BSMP Well, in code, just as in life, there's hardly enough information to definitively say that one way is the best way; but, some developers speak in absolutes to the point that for them, perhaps, they'll say "the best way".  I just didn't want to open that can of worms :)

Comment: I meant from a grammar standpoint. (Well, I'm not 100% certain on that but it *sounds* wrong to say "Maybe there is the best way" instead of just "Maybe the best way".)