# How did I get the Quorum badge when I don't have any post on Meta with a score of 2 or more?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, meta

How did I get the Quorum badge when I don't have any post on Meta with a score of 2 or more?

I have many posts with negative scores but none with positive ones.

Are posts with negative scores considered too? Or is it because it's not the overall score and two people have upvoted it?

Comment: You got the badge on [Jan 29](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum?userid=16136190), it might be related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415574/how-did-this-edit-get-approved) question (though it had a score of -1 of that date) or a deleted question (please which we won't be able to see).

Comment: As always, you can see your deleted questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current)

Comment: Just to clarify, the badge would be given at the moment when the condition of "overall score = 2" was fulfilled, and the badge won't be retracted if the condition is not fulfilled anymore, even if the post has a negative score and deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you got it from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415689/feature-request-for-flagging-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-multiple-questions), which I found reviewing your [badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3/editor?userid=16136190) here. Though it is impossible for me to tell what order the votes on it were cast, it has a score of +5/-7 and received a score of +3/-6 on the first day, meaning it could have easily had a score of +2 for a period of time. The fact it then ended up with a negative score and later deleted doesn't matter; badges aren't revoked.

The fact that it was posted on the same day you got the badge, and that none of your undeleted questions could have given you the badge makes this as strong a candidate as I can find, without having access to your deleted questions.

Comment: This is correct. The question sat at +3 for a while before attracting downvotes.